# Generic Confusion on Inheritence -- Java

Tags: java, generics

So I'll spare you the giant blocks of code and cut to the chase. I have two classes: one a base "AbstractNode" class and the other a "TokenRingNode" class. The signature for AbstractNode is this:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode <E extends NetworkEvent>
```

Then the signature for TokenRingNode:

```
public class TokenRingNode extends AbstractNode<TokenRingEvent>
```

I have a method in AbstractNode that is:

```
public abstract void createEvent(AbstractNode<E> destinationNode);
```

I have also tried:

```
public abstract <N extends AbstractNode<E>> createEvent (N destinationNode)
```

Then in TokenRingNode, I override this abstract method with:

```
public void createEvent(TokenRingNode destinationNode) { ... }
```

The problem is, the compiler does not believe that this is a valid override and I am not exactly sure why. TokenRingNode extends Abstract, so can someone illustrate to me why this method is not a valid override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to define two generics for this in AbstractNode:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode <E extends NetworkEvent, A extends AbstractNode>
...
public abstract void createEvent(A destinationNode);
```

and then subclass it as

```
public class TokenRingNode extends AbstractNode<TokenRingEvent, TokenRingNode>
```

Comment: THIS is the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a valid override, but not because of generics.

If you have an `AbstractNode`, it's reasonable to expect that you should be able to call `createEvent()` on it with another `AbstractNode` as a parameter. But you never define this method on `TokenRingNode`.

e.g. ignoring generics for the moment:

```
AbstractNode n1 = new TokenRingNode();
AbstractNode n2 = new TokenRingNode();
n1.createEvent(n2); // this should work by the contract of AbstractNode, but you never define it
```

Comment: So then is the only solution to provide a 2nd createEvent method? eg: @Override the first AND create one that accepts TokenRingNode that essentially calls the first but has some casts? specifically : public void createEvent(TokenRingNode destinationNode) {
  createEvent((AbstractNode<TokenRingEvent>)destinationNode);
 }

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the superclass contract promises it accepts `AbstractNode<E>` as a parameter, however, you expect a `TokenRingNode`  specifically , which is only of of the classes that (so a subclass of what it promises to accept. Hence your subclass is accepting less classes than the superclass contract promises.

Comment: Right, so how can I generalize that AbstractNode<E> to say something along the lines of "Some class that is a subclass of AbstractNode<E>"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more generic type to AbstractNode, because the event and the destination node can have two different types:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode <E extends NetworkEvent, N extends AbstractNode<E, N>>
{
    public abstract void createEvent(N destinationNode);
}
```

and then this will compile:

```
public class TokenRingNode extends AbstractNode<TokenEvent, TokenRingNode>
{
    public void createEvent(TokenRingNode destinationNode){
    }
}
```

You cannot do just

```
public abstract <N extends AbstractNode<E>> createEvent (N destinationNode)
```

because then you declare the createEvent method to accept ANY AbstractNode<E extends NetworkEvent> as a parameter. But you want it to accept only the TokenRingEvent, and that's why you need to push the type declaration one level higher.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractNode<TokenRingEvent>` is not necessarily a `TokenRingNode` therefore you can’t override

```
public abstract void createEvent(AbstractNode<TokenRingEvent> destinationNode);
```

with

```
public void createEvent(TokenRingNode destinationNode);
```

It's not related to generics / type erasures, the signature is just different. A `AbstractNode<TokenRingEvent> destinationNode` is not a `TokenRingMode` (but the opposite, yes).